# React Native native iOS component is blank

Tags: objective-c, react-native, react-native-ios

I created a new project and followed the tutorial for native iOS UI components (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html). However, when I compile and run my code, it's just a blank screen. I don't see any errors.

I know that my native `view` method is being called, but I'm not sure why the MKMapView isn't being rendered.

`index.ios.js`:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
const MapView = require('./MapView.ios');

export default class NativeTest extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    // backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('NativeTest', () => NativeTest);
```

`MapView.ios.js`:

```
// @flow

import { requireNativeComponent } from 'react-native';
module.exports = requireNativeComponent('RCTMapView');
```

`RCTMapViewManager.m`:

```
// RCTMapViewManager.m
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

#import "RCTViewManager.h"

@interface RCTMapViewManager : RCTViewManager
@end

@implementation RCTMapViewManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (UIView *)view
{
  return [[MKMapView alloc] init];
}

@end
```

How do I get the returned `UIView` to be rendered within my React Native app?

Comment: If both JustifyContent and alignItems are "center" you may need to set width and height to your mapview.

Comment: check if it is on release mode.

Comment: @EnieJakiro: You're correct. Removing the `alignItems` and `justifyContent` and setting `flex: 1` on the `MapView` worked.

Comment: @AndrewHassan i could answer the question if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by removing the `alignItems` and `justifyContent` styles from the container and adding a `flex: 1` style to the `MapView`.